# Meaning of $\overline {g(x)}$

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of $\overline {g(x)}$?

To put this into context, in my notes I have,

$$\langle f,g\rangle_{L_2 (\mathbb{R})}= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \overline{g(x)} \, dx$$

How is $g(x)$ different to $\overline{g(x)}$?

Comment: In this context, it likely stands for complex conjugate.

Comment: I changed $<f,g>$ to $\langle f,g\rangle$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @amd is right. See [Wikipedia: Square-integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) where the same standard notation is used.

Answer (score 4):

That refers to the complex conjugation $\overline{x+iy} = x-iy$. It ensures that
$$ \langle f,g\rangle_{L_2 (\mathbb{R})}= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \overline{g(x)} \, dx
$$
is an inner product since it must satisfy $\langle f, f\rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle f, g\rangle = \overline{\langle g, f\rangle}$

Comment: In mathematics we write $\overline{f(x)}$ for this.  But in physics they write $f(x)^*$ for this.

Answer (score 0):

This probably refers to the complex conjugate, which, for any complex number, has the same real part and magnitude of imaginary part but opposite sign on te imaginary part. For example, if $f(x) = 5+4i$, then $\overline{f(x)} = 5-4i$